# Is the mux in this golang socket.io example necessary?

Tags: go, socket.io

In an app that I'm making, a user is always part of a 'game'. I'd like to set up a socket.io server to communicate with users in a game. I'm planning to use http://godoc.org/github.com/madari/go-socket.io go-socket.io, which defines the `newSocketIO`function to create a new socketio instance.

Instead of creating one socketio instance, I thought it might be possible to create a map that maps game id's to socket.io instances, and configure them so that they listen on an url that represents the game id.

This way, I can use methods such as broadcast and broadcastExcept to broadcast to all players ithin a single game. However, I'd have to start a new goroutine for every game, and I don't know enough about their performance characteristics to know if this is scalable, since the request rate for a single socketio instance will be very low, about 1/second at peak times, but the connection might be idle for tens of seconds at other times (except for heartbeat, and possibly other communication specified by the socket.io protocol).

Would I be better off creating 1 socket.io instance, and tracking which connections belong to which games?

Answer (score 3):

> I'd have to start a new goroutine for every game, and I don't know enough about their performance characteristics to know if this is scalable

Fire away, the Go scheduler is built to efficiently handle thousands and even millions of goroutines.

The default `net/http` server in the Go standard library spawns a goroutine for every client for instance.

Just remember to return from your goroutines once they're done working. Else you'll end up with a lot of stale ones.

> Would I be better off creating 1 socket.io instance, and tracking which connections belong to which games?

I'm not involved in the project but if it follows Go's *"get sh*t done"* philosophy, then it shouldn't matter. You can find out what works better by profiling both approaches though.

Comment: Good answer. But I'm wondering why you didn't vote up the question. Is there a reason?

Comment: Thank you. No particular reason; I normally vote up questions from which I can learn or which show an especially profound research.